# Error: 'At-rule or selector expected' in SCSS when using Vue.js - How to Fix?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, sass

I'm working on a Vue.js project and using SCSS for styling. I have the following code in my App.vue component:

```
<template>
  <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png" />
  <HelloWorld msg="Welcome to Your Vue.js App" />
  <p>weqt</p>
</template>

<script>
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue';

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    HelloWorld,
  },
};
</script>

<style lang="scss">
$color: red; // shown error here
body {
  background-color: $color;
  p {
    color: white;
  }
}
</style>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3aC0.png)

However, I'm encountering the following error: 'At-rule or selector expectedcss(css-ruleorselectorexpected). But,The Scss syntax applies to web pages correctly, Can someone please explain why I'm getting this error and how I can fix it?

What's puzzling is that other team members who are using the same codebase do not encounter this error.

Your assistance in resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your VS Code IDE is not recognizing the `lang="scss"` attribute in your style tag.  If your team members manually removed the attribute they'd see the same error.  The fact you have the error _with_ the attribute is a sign that some config or setting in your IDE is incorrect.  Unfortunately I don't know what that setting would be, but maybe someone else will have a better idea, or you can try copying all the same IDE settings as one of your team members.